# Why don't I need to solve the edge case of a system of linear inequalities in one variable?

Tags: inequality

Note: Original question was not worded clearly. Please see edit.

Recently I was learning about how to solve for x in an inequality of this form:
$\\ ax+b<cx+d<ex+f$ (a, b, c, d, e, f are constants; inequality signs may be "$\leq$" )
I was taught that we only needed to solve $ax+b<cx+d$ and $cx+d<ex+f$ and not $ax+b<ex+f$ but I do not understand why. My math teacher said it was due to transitivity, but I don't see how.

I tried to simplify the general form, letting $0<a<c<e$ and $0<b<d<f$:
$\\ ax+b<cx+d \implies (a-c)x<d-b \implies x>\frac{d-b}{a-c}$, $\\ cx+d<ex+f \implies (c-e)x<f-d \implies x>\frac{f-d}{c-e}$,
$\\ ax+b<ex+f \implies (a-e)x<f-b \implies x>\frac{f-b}{a-e}$
But then I would get stuck as I cannot prove $\frac{d-b}{a-c}<\frac{f-d}{c-e}<\frac{f-b}{a-e}$.

I am seriously at a loss, and any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: What I meant to say was, in an system of inequalities $A<B<C$, why is it redundant to solve $A<C$?

Comment: Write $A=ax+b$, $B=cx+d$ and $C:=ex+f$. Then you ask why $A<B<C$ implies $A<C$. This is true for all real numbers. No need to do computations with $a,b,c,d,e,f,x$ for transitivity.

Comment: Yes, but I can't be sure that when I solve $A<B$ into the form of $x>p$, $B<C$ into $x>q$, $A<C$ into $x>r$, that r is between p and q.

Comment: Proof is trivial. Assume positive denominator. x1/y1 < x2/y2 ⇒ x1*y2 < x2*y1. If we add x1*y1 to both side, we get x1/y1 < (x1+x2)/(y1+y2).  If we add x2*y2 to both side, we get (x1+x2)/(y1+y2) < x2/y2.

Comment: If you have $A = B = C$, why is it necessary to solve only two of $A = B$, $B = C$, $A = C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps turning inequality to equality may make things clear.

$a < b\quad ⇒\; ε_a = b-a > 0$
$b < c\quad ⇒\; ε_b = c-b > 0$

$c - a = (c-b)+(b-a) = (ε_b + ε_a) > 0$

Thus, it is redundant to solve again for $a<c$, because it is always true.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, $a<b \land b<c \implies (ε_a>0 \land ε_b >0 \equiv ε_c >0)$?

Comment: Yes, if you mean ε(c) = c-a

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if I were forced to pick a general rule, I would contend that $a<b<c$ **means** $A<B\land B<C$. For instance, I would read $A\ne 0\ne B$ as $A\ne0\land 0\ne B$, and *not* as $A\ne0\land 0\ne B\land A\ne C$, just like I don't read $A\in B\in C$ as $A\in B\land B\in C\land A\in C$. The fact that $A<B\land B<C$ implies $A<C$ would then be incidental. Anyways, since interpreation of $a\diamond b\diamond c$ when $\diamond$ isn't a transitive relation is a magnet for nuisances, let's say that the point of your contention is why you can say that $$(A<B\land B<C)\Leftrightarrow (A<B\land B<C\land A<C)$$

As you've been told, $<$ has the property that for all $A$, $B$ and $C$, $A<B\land B<C$ implies $A<C$. Whenever you have a condition $P$ which is implied by a condition $Q$ (i.e. that $P$ is true whenever $Q$ is), you can safely assume that $(P\land Q)\Leftrightarrow P$.

$[(P\land Q)\Rightarrow Q]$ is true because $P\land Q$ is true if and only if both $P$ and $Q$ are, and therefore $P$ is true whenever $P\land Q$ is true.

$[Q\Rightarrow (P\land Q)]$ is true because if $Q$ is true, then $P$ is true too by hypothesis. Therefore $P\land Q$ is true.

Comment: Oh dear. I think my question isn't worded clearly. I understand why $a<b \land b<c \implies a<c$, but what I don't understand is why it is redundant to solve $a<c$.